# Shared Data Storage Strategy for 'Live' Dashboards in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, datastore, data-storage

I'm doing an UI in excel which the goal is to have "live" information on `Orders` and `Order Status` between three users, I'll name them `DataUser`, `DashboardOne`, and `DashboardTwo` for examples sake.

The process is that the `DataUser` will fill in the Orders data, that data is going to be used to populate information on two dashboards. The dashboards are going to be updated live with changes from the `DataUser`(Orders Increases/Decreases), and changes on order status between `DashboardOne` and `DashboardTwo`. For the live updates I'm thinking on using `Application.OnTime` event call to refresh the View/Dashboards. The two dashboards will be active about 8 hours a day.

Where I'm struggling in on how/where to store the Data, I've though about a couple of options but I don't know the implications of one over the other, especially considering that I intend that the dashboards will run/refresh every 30 sec. with `Application.OnTime` which could prove expensive.

The options I thought about where:

- A Master Workbook that would create separate Workbooks for `DashboardOne` and `DashboardTwo` and act database and main UI for `DataUser`.
- Three separate workbooks that would all refer to the one DataWorkbook or another flat data file (perhaps and XML or JSON).
- Using an actual database for the data, although this would bring other implications (don't currently have one).

I'm not considering a shared workbook as I've tried something similar in the past (and this time ^^, early steps) and it went rather poorly, nightmare to sync and poor data integrity.

**In short:**
Which would be the best Data storage strategy for Excel that wouldn't jeopardise the integrity of the data nor be so expensive as to interfere with the uptime rest of the code? Are there better options that I should be considering?

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a number of alternatives, depending on the time you want to invest and the tools at hand. I'll give you a couple of options here.

But first, the basic assumptions:

1. The amount of data items that you need to share (being a dashboard) is of few tens (let's say, less than 100),
2. You have at least basic programming skills,
3. From your description, you have one client with READ-WRITE capabilities while there are two clients with READ-ONLY capability.

**OPTION 1**:
You can have the Excel saving the data in CSV format (very small amount of data and hence it would take a small fraction of a second to save it and to read it).

The two clients would then open the file in read-only mode, load the data and update the display. You would need to include exception handling at both types of client:

1. At the one writing, handle the condition of error when it attempts to write at the same time one of the clients attempts to read,
2. At the two reading, handle the condition of error when attempting to open the file (for read only) while the other process is writing.

Since the write and read operations are going to take a very, VERY short time (as stated, a small fraction of a second), these conditions will be very rare. Additional, since both dashboard clients would be open the file for read-only, they will not disturb each other if they make their attempt at the same moment.

If you wish to drastically reduce the chances of collision, you may set the timers (of the update process on one hand and of the reading processes on the other) to be a primary number of seconds. For instance, the timer of the updating process would be every 11 seconds while that of the reading process would be every 7 seconds.

**OPTION 2**:
Establish a TCP/IP channel between the processes, where the main process (meaning the one that would have WRITE privilege) would send a triggering message to the other two requesting to start an update whenever a new version of the data had been saved. Upon reception of the trigger, both READ-ONLY processes would approach the file and fetch the data.

In this case, the chances of collision would become near to null.